# Transformation of skewed independent variables with negative values

Tags: regression, data-transformation

I have a bunch of independent variables which are skewed and have negative and zero values. I am seeing a lot of suggestions of using cube root as a transformation.

What would be the harm in using $\text{sign}(x)\log(1+|x|)$ instead?

Comment: Why are you transforming these independent variables?

Comment: Because the distributions are very skewed and outliers prone. I'm Afraid that it'll affect the estimates.

Comment: What do you intend to do with these variables (after a possible transformation)?

Comment: Use it as a predictor in a logistic regression

Comment: Why do you think skewness or outliers are a problem for these variables?

Answer (score 4):

One reason to avoid such a transformation is that it will make the interpretation of the regression coefficient *very* difficult.

Moreover, there is no requirement for independent variables to be normally distributed, and as a rule you should avoid doing so unless there are substantive reasons for it, such as a known nonlinear relationship, to deal with heteroscedasticity, or to *help* interpretation